# Mutual Information for Continuous Random variables for system with 1 input and multiple outputs (SIMO System)

Tags: information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

Let's consider channels of the form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:channelmodel2}
Y_{1}= X e^{j \theta_{1}}+ V_1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:channelmodel3}
Y_{2}=X e^{j \theta_{2}}+ V_2
\end{equation}

Where $X$ is the channel input symbol. $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are outputs. $V_{i}$ is complex white Gaussian noise with (known) variance $\sigma^{2},$ i.e., $\sigma^{2}/2$ per dimension. Both channels parameters $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ are independent of each other. In simple words, it is a single input multiple output (SIMO) system. I am interested to compute $I(X; Y_1, Y_2)$. Can you please guide me on whether I am doing right or wrong?
\begin{equation}\label{eq:channelmodel4}
\begin{aligned}
I(X; Y_1, Y_2)& = h( Y_1, Y_2) - h(Y_1, Y_2 | X) \\
&= h(Y_1) + h(Y_2|Y_1) - h(Y_1| X) - h(Y_2 | X , Y_1)\\
&\overset{\text{by independence}}{=} h(Y_1) + h(Y_2) - h(Y_1| X) - h(Y_2 | X )\\
&= I(X; Y_1) + I(X; Y_2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: A point for concern for me is that you assumed that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent which is not true given the relations you give. In SIMO systems I would expect  $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to be correlated, after all both signals were radiated from the same source antenna, the only difference is that they were received by antennas with some separation in between them.

Comment: Thank you. I understood my mistake. You are right I cannot proceed from the 2nd line onwards in the upper equation. Please guide me; y1 and y2 are independent given x, am I right?  h(y1,y2|x) = h(y1|x) + h(y2|x) . And how the correlation and entropy can be linked? I am trying to know the impact of correlation among variables on entropy (in form of mathematical expression).

Comment: You need to provide additional information regarding the "channel" parameters $\theta$. How are they distributed and who is aware of their value (TX, RX, both, or none)? Then you can refer to the literature for MIMO capacity since your model is a special case of the general one (although, depending on the channel knowledge information assumptions, it may not have a closed form formula)

Comment: $\theta$ in my case is the Wiener process (phase noise). The receiver knows only the statistics of this phase noise. I also know the closed-form expression is not possible. However, I am looking for mutual information expressed in terms of probabilities or entropies of individual received antennas observations ($Y's$). Other way to look at it is $I(X;Y_1, Y_2) = H(X) - H(X | Y1, Y2)$. Here $H(X)$ can be easily computed. However, I am struggling to find 2nd term.

Comment: Maybe start from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08644.pdf) and references therein. This is for the single antenna case, I think the same authors have considered the multi-antenna case in other works.